# How can I change the way TextView lays out its content?

Tags: android, textview

I'd like to force a `TextView` to use my own logic to lay out its content, i.e. break the text into lines (the text may contain spans). Can I do that? How?

Comment: What do you mean by "lay out its content"?

Comment: what do u wnt TextView to "layout its content"?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add line breaks, you can use "\n". I don't think you can make it use different formatting, but you could make a function to convert formatting before you update the TextView if you need to use existing formatting.